# Oracle SQL - UNION ALL on user defined clob types returning null values instead of data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Given the following two types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
type clob_nt as table of clob;
/
```

I am trying to use them in a 'union all' statement

```
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(xslt.children as clob_nt)) temp, col6
    from tableA
    union all
    Select a,b,c,d,e,cast(multiset(temp.col1 from table(cast(tableB.children as clob_nt)) temp, col7
from tableB
```

The problem i am having is that if i run the second part of the union on its own i get two rows returned. If i run the full query i get no rows returned.

Is there something in Oracle that causes problems when unioning clob/nested table types?

I will try and reproduce it in sqlfiddle

### Update

I just found out that the same query works fine in a different copy of the database. The DBA seems to think it might be related with how the Optimiser works. Not quite sure what that means.

Comment: Any chance you could come up with a simple, reproducible test case that demonstrates the problem?  Give us the DDL to create a table, the DDL to create the type, the DML to insert a couple of rows, and demonstrate the issue (or create a test case on sqlfiddle and give us a link).  As it stands, it's hard to provide a lot of help both because it's hard to follow the question-- I'm wagering that there is a lot of code that is unnecessary to reproduce the problem-- and because we can't easily reproduce the problem locally to test.